# I'm optimizing my django project backend, but I got many problems on "list_display" that contains ForeignKey

Tags: django, optimization, django-admin

django masters all around the world
I'm Korean developer and started django 3 months ago.

Now I'm just a slave of my company.
Anyway, I have problem on optimizing django admin project, but no one has experienced the same problem.

This is my models "Project", "Answer", "Request".

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Model   : Project
# Description : project model
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
class Project(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '     project'
        verbose_name_plural = '     project'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Model   : Request
# Description : Request model
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
class Request(models.Model):
       
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='client')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='project')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Subclass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='product')
    
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Develop, verbose_name='category')
    
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.CharField('price', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.CharField('duedate', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField('content', null=True)
    file = models.FileField('file', upload_to=request_update_filename, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('created_at', default=time)
    
    add_meeting = models.BooleanField('add_meeting', default=False, null=True)
    
    examine = models.BooleanField('check examing', default=False, null=True)
    active_save = models.BooleanField('active-save', default=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '     request'
        verbose_name_plural = '     requests'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Answer(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="client")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="project", null=True)
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="partner")
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '     Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = '     Answer'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

and this is my admin code

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RequestInline,AnswerInline]
    list_display = ['request_name','client_email','project_price','project_created','count_answer','count_meeting','answer_status']

    def request_name(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        request_name = Request.objects.get(project = project_id)
        return request_name
        
    def client_email(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        client = Request.objects.get(project=project_id).client
        return client
        
    def client_phone(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        client = Request.objects.get(project=project_id).client
        phone = User.objects.get(username=client).phone
        return phone
    
    def project_price(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        request_price = Request.objects.get(project=project_id).price
        return request_price

    def project_created(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        created_at = Request.objects.get(project=project_id).created_at
        return created_at

    def count_answer(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        answer_qs = Answer.objects.all()
        answer = Answer.objects.filter(project=project_id)
        count = len(answer)
        return count

    def count_meeting(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        answer_yes = Answer.objects.filter(project = project_id, state = 1)
        count = len(answer_yes)
        return count
        
    def answer_status(self, obj):
        project_id = obj.id
        answer = Answer.objects.filter(project = project_id, info_check =1)
        count = len(answer)
        return count
```

There are many factors not included in the above, but what I want to solve is not to bring in the same queryset(Request, Answer).
The project itself is a structure that does not have attributes but is received only by foreign keys. Such a structure is making it difficult to find a solution.

I used select_related(prefetch_related too), but it does not work.

If you can give me some advice, I'd like to take some advice. thanks.

p.s. It is my first time asking question on this site, I apologize if there was anything rude.

Answer (score 0):

`admin.TabularInline` will show the **reverse foreign key** in the admin detail page that may help you, but it seems that you have already used it in the inlines of `ProjectAdmin`.

Comment: Well, I think     *admin.TabularInline* is about detail page. but my problem is about
    *list_display* (before detail page)